# Evaluate $\iint_{S}xz\,dy\,dz$ where $S=\{(x,y,z)\mid x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0,2x+2y+z=2\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

**Problem**

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\mid x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0,2x+2y+z=2\}$, and $a=(2,2,1)$ be a normal vector oriented outside. Evaluate the surface integral $$\iint_{S}xz\,dy\,dz$$

I am having a hard time interpreting this question since every surface integral I have ever seen was in a form $\iint_{S}f(x,y,z)\,dS$. I don't even know what this integral even means.

If it was in a form $\iint_{S}f(x,y,z)\,dS$ then I can calculate using the method written [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx), but I am not even sure what is the first step.

What would be the first step to solve this question? Any help is appreciated.

By the way, the normal vector $a$ may be unnecessary to the question. If it is not required to solve it, you can ignore it.

Comment: Check your source! The set $S$ is a bona fide surface, and $S$ is oriented when we think of $a$ as the "positive" normal. But the integral $\int\!\!\int_S xz\> dydz$ makes no sense. $\int\!\!\int_S xz \ dy\wedge dz$ or $\int\!\!\int_S xz\> {\rm d}\omega$, where ${\rm d}\omega$ is the scalar surface element, would be o.k.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I checked the source again, and I think it says what I said here. https://gyazo.com/55fbc02fca01e02e92fba4ec6d89ab30 It's in Japanese though. The first part of the question says "Let S be the intersection of plane 2x+2y+z=2 with x≧0,y≧0,z≧0 and let a=(2,2,1) be a normal vector oriented outside. Find the next surface integral".

Comment: But I agree that the question does not make sense. Maybe I have to ask the lecturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it means is you have a scalar field $f(x,y,z) = xz$ instead of a vector field.

Your surface is a plane given by $2x+2y+z=2 \,$ where $(x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0)$.

Given the integral is wrt $y, z$, rewrite your plane in the form $g(y,z) = x = 1 - y - \frac{z}{2} \,$.

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = - 1, \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = - \frac{1}{2}$

Based on your parametrization, your projected triangle in YZ plane $(x = 0)$ gives you upper bound of $y$ as $(1-\frac{z}{2})$ and upper bound of $z$ as $2$.

Your integral becomes $\displaystyle \iint_S (1 - y - \frac{z}{2}) z \, \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})^2} \, dy \, dz$

Comment: Why is it equal to $\iint_S (1 - y - \frac{z}{2}) z \, \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})^2} \, dy \, dz$? Shouldn't $S$ here be the orthogonal projection of $S$?

Comment: if your question is specifically why $dy \, dz$ instead of $dS$, please note the integral says $\iint_S$ and so you have to integrate over $S$. From the link you have sent, you can see $\iint\limits_{S}{{f\left( {x,y,z} \right)\,dS}} = \iint\limits_{D}{{f\left( {\vec r\left( {u,v} \right)} \right)\left\| {{{\vec r}_u} \times {{\vec r}_v}} \right\|\,dA}}$. You can see $dA$ on the right hand side instead of $dS$ and $dA$ is nothing but $dy \, dz$ or $dx \, dy$ ... based on how you parametrized your surface.

Comment: Also the reason you ignore normal vector $\hat{n}$ because it is a scalar field and not a vector field. I hope I now understood your question correctly.

Comment: So, should I interpret $\iint_{S} xzdydz$ as $\iint_{S} xzdS$, if I follow the notation on the website?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But please make sure when you convert it into double integral, you parametrize your surface as $x = g(y,z)$ as the question asks you to specifically use $dy \, dz$.